# QGIS Value based arrows

Tags: qgis, symbology, formatting

Although i've seen some similar treads, I don't manage to quite solve my problem.
I've added a delimited text layer that includes coordinates of 2 points. I want to make arrows between these points that vary in size based on a fifth column value.

I created arrows by a geometry generator with the following expression:

```
make_line( make_point(  "OR_Lon",  "Or_Lat" ),make_point(  "DES_Lon" , "DES_Lat" ))
```

After setting the symbology to 'graduated' i can change the colors based on the value, but the size is not working. Anyone an idea to fix this?

[image: This is an example of the colour graduation, but i prefer size if possible]

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? In QGIS 3.8, if you select the _Arrow_ symbol in the Symbol Selector menu, you can set the _Arrow width_ and assign this to your fifth field.

Comment: I can confirm that the field-controlled *arrow width* setting also works in QGIS 3.4 in an arrow symbol inside a geometry generator.